# Java cant seem to get one side of a table to print correctly

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and am having a really tough time trying to get certain codes to work properly. Recently I've been having trouble with a table I have to design in the console. It's a conversion of kilos to pounds AND pounds to kilos. my problem is that for some reason when I go to print the table, it will run through and print 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 on the kilos to pounds side whereas on the other side it operates perfectly fine. My guess is that it was from running two loops at the same time, any advice helps, this has been bothering me for quite some time..... I'll list the code below:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class mian55 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Kilograms   Pounds" + "     |     " + "Pounds   Kilolograms");

        for(int kilogram = 1; kilogram<200; kilogram = kilogram+2){         
            DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.0");   
            for(int poundage = 20; poundage<516; poundage= poundage+5){
                DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
                System.out.println(kilogram + "          " + decimal.format(kilogram * 2.2) +"         |       " + (poundage + "          " + decim.format(poundage / 2.2)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `kilogram` variable from the outer loop will not change for every cycle of the inner loop, causing your first and second columns to be duplicated for as many times as the inner loop runs. Try incrementing both variables on each loop, like so (variables shortened for brevity):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class mian55 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Kilograms  Pounds   |   Pounds   Kilograms");

        int kgs = 1;
        int lbs = 20;
        for (; kgs < 200 && lbs < 516; kgs += 2, lbs += 5){
            DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.0");   
            System.out.println(String.format(" %7d  %7s    | %7d  %7s",
                    kgs, decimal.format(kgs * 2.2), lbs, decimal.format(lbs / 2.2)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't understand the reason why it kept replicating itself. I couldn't figure out how to put everything into a single for loop. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to create a conversion table.

Here's the results from one program.

```
Kilograms    Pounds     |     Pounds   Kilolograms
       10     22.00     |         10          4.55
       20     44.00     |         20          9.09
       30     66.00     |         30         13.64
       40     88.00     |         40         18.18
       50    110.00     |         50         22.73
       60    132.00     |         60         27.27
       70    154.00     |         70         31.82
       80    176.00     |         80         36.36
       90    198.00     |         90         40.91
      100    220.00     |        100         45.45
      110    242.00     |        110         50.00
      120    264.00     |        120         54.55
      130    286.00     |        130         59.09
      140    308.00     |        140         63.64
      150    330.00     |        150         68.18
      160    352.00     |        160         72.73
      170    374.00     |        170         77.27
      180    396.00     |        180         81.82
      190    418.00     |        190         86.36
      200    440.00     |        200         90.91
```

I used the same values for the left hand side of the tables.  This allowed me to use one for loop.

Java class names start with a capital letter.

I used the format method of String, rather than DecimalFormat, so I could adjust the spacing to match the header.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class Conversions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Kilograms    Pounds" + "     |     " + "Pounds   Kilolograms");

        for (int value = 10; value <= 200; value += 10) {
            float pounds = (float) value * 2.2F;
            float kilograms = (float) value / 2.2F;

            String v = String.format("%9d", value);
            String p = String.format("%10s", String.format("%5.2f", pounds));
            String k = String.format("%14s", String.format("%5.2f", kilograms));

            System.out.println(v + p + "     |  " + v + k);
        }
    }
}
```